# create a registration form

Tags: mysql, forms, isset, is-empty

(I have some problems when i insert into the form the user&email&password it wasn't added to database I  wanna the value which i add to this registration form to appear in the database on php my admin there's my code i don't know what the wrong about it

```
require "connect.php";
echo "<br>";

if(!empty($_POST))
{
    if(isset($_POST['user'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['pass']))
    {
        $user=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
        $email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
         $pass=md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']));
             if(!empty($user)&&!empty($email)&&!empty($pass))
        {


          $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO user(username,email,password) VALUES('$user','$email','$pass')");
                }
            }
          }
          ?>
<html>
<head><title>sign up</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="user" placeholder="username">Username</td><br><br>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E_mail">email</td><br><br>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="password">password</td><br><br>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="sub" value="sign up"></td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

my connect.php page

```
<?php
$connect=new mysqli ('localhost','eman','password','registration');
if($connect->connect_errno)
{
    die("connect error :".$connect->connect_errno);
}
else
{
    echo "connected successfully";
}
```

tablename in my data base :user 
database name :registration
fields :id/username/email/password

Comment: Show your `connect.php`

Comment: Show your connect.php and check table name,field name  and data type(length of data type)

Comment: I edited the post above tell me if I missing something

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Your `connect.php` is defining a mysqli connection `$connect` which is never used in the other page. Further, you're using `mysql_*` functions on the other page instead of the `mysqli_*` functions one would expect to use with `$connect`.